# is it possible to restrict access by using ipaddress?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, https

I have recently installed ssl certificate to a site.

I tried accessing the site using ip address

```
133.255.214.180
```

it redirects to

```
https://133.255.214.180/
```

it then shows that "your connection is not private" ssl certificate error. I had bought ssl certificate for domain name and not ip address.

when i access using the domain name for example

```
www.example.com
```

then it redirects to

```
https://www.example.com
```

without ssl certificate error.

I used redirection in nginx as

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name 133.255.214.180;

  return 301 https://www.example.com;

}
```

I want to make it so that when the user types in the ip address at the url bar of the browser then it redirects to the domain name i.e https://www.example.com so that it doesnt show ssl certificate error. Is this possible to achieve?

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS handshake is done before sending the actual request, so if you type https://something_without_valid_cert you will always receive that error.

With sending the request I mean even "opening" the HTTP communication, including sending back the redirect.

The reason is very simple, if the certificate is not valid you cannot trust the server, it could respond with anything, including a malicious redirect.

Your nginx configuration should work if you type http://the_ip_address. Because you send back a 301 (Moved Permanently) the browser next time will perform the redirect automatically without calling the server.